# Return values from both futures, where one future is "cancelled"

Tags: rust

I have a method `copy` that accepts two streams and returns the number of bytes copied from stream A to stream B (both streams have been split in a reader/writer pair to deal with ownership issues).

```rust
async fn copy(a: ReadStream, b: WriteStream) -> usize {
  // code here
}
```

Now I run both methods and gather their futures and invoke `select!` to ensure that it returns if one of the copy methods complete. The other copy is cancelled automatically, because the future is dropped.

This code will look something like this:

```rust
let a_to_b = copy(a_read, b_write).fuse();
let b_to_a = copy(b_read, a_write).fuse();
pin_mut!(qtt, ttq);
select! {
  bytes_a_to_b = a_to_b => { /* save the a-to-b bytes copied */ },
  bytes_b_to_a = b_to_a => { /* save the b-to-a bytes copied */ },
}
return (bytes_a_to_b, b_to_a);
```

Because the second future is dropped, there is no way to get the number of bytes that has been copied by that future. How can I get both values?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `copy` method and it now takes a `&mut usize` argument that is constantly updated with the number of bytes that has been copied.

```rust
async fn copy(a: ReadStream, b: WriteStream, bytes_copied: &mut usize) {
  // code here
}
```

Then I use the following code:

```
let (mut bytes_a_to_b, mut bytes_b_to_a) = (0usize, 0usize);
{
  let a_to_b = copy(a_read, b_write, &mut bytes_a_to_b).fuse();
  let b_to_a = copy(b_read, a_write, &mut bytes_b_to_a).fuse();
  pin_mut!(qtt, ttq);
  select! {
    _ = a_to_b => {},
    _ = b_to_a => {},
  }
}
return (bytes_a_to_b, b_to_a);
```

Although this works fine, it seems a bit of a hack.